# Missing Lexicon Receptacle

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know this has been asked twice before, but I'm not sure what is wrong with my game because I don't run the "Wearable Elder Scrolls" mod. I have other mods, but nothing (that I know of) involving the Elder Scrolls. In the Discerning the Transmundane quest, the base of the receptacle is visible, but the stand itself that the cube goes in is gone. The arrow marker is hovering just above it but there is nothing to click on. If anyone knows what mod might be a the cause I'd appreciate knowing before I try and disable the 20+ mods I have running! Playing on XB1.

[image]

List of mods I'm using:

```
Campfire: Complete Camping System 
Unofficial Skyrim SE Patch 
Waterview - Skyrim version 
Dark Brotherhood Forever to Misc 
God Gear XB1 [XB1]
Rich Merchants of Skyrim [XB1]
Ring of Increased Carry Weight [XB1]
Unlimited Rings and Amulets 
Mornfallow Manor [XB1] 
Routa - Stormcloak and Warrior Cabin 
Unique Taverns-Nightgate Inn 
Skyrim Scroll Crafting 
Skyrim Graphic Overhaul 
Enhanced Blood Textures 
rskyrimchildren.esp (XB1 fix)
BDO Shudad Armor v2 
thescarlett.esp 
isilnarsil.esp 
better leveling.esp 
KS Hairdos Lite 
Adorable Females 
beautifulmistressv2.1.esp
Natural Eyes 
Kissing - Immersive Lovers 
Lush Overhaul [Xbox One] 
Dragon Carved Armor [XB1] 
Skyrim SE Expanded 
Skyrim Weapons 
Better Auriels Bow 
Windstad Mine - XB1
projecthippie.esp 
Craftable Everything: Dawnguard 
Marriage All XBox1 
Dragonborn Crafting Hall SE 
A Quality World Map - Vivid with stone roads [XB1] 
Lampposts of Skyrim:SE 
Dark Water Home (XB1) 
Wearable Lanterns 
Less Grass and Such [Xbox] 
Dragons' Bane- A Player House 
dwarven home.esp 
The Forgotten City 
Dovahkiin Keep XB1 
Relationship Dialogue Overhaul 
Imperious-Races of Skyrim
The Temple of Time 
Kokiri's Valley 
Wispering Waters XB1 
Craftable clothing [XBOX1] 
Heljarchen Pool and Hot Bath EXtra for SE 
Heljarchen Farm -XB1 
Draco's Heljarchen Manor Upgrade 
Become High King of Skyrim V2 
Ars Metallica 
Dragon Claw Stands 
Gildergreen Regrown 
The Paarthurnax Dilemma 
Marco's Integrated Leveled Lists 
Color patches remover 
Storefront 
Cutting Room Floor 
Cheatroom (XB1) 
Skyland 1k - A Landscape texture 
Halls of Dovahndor by OKIIR [XB1] 
Go Away Map Clouds! [XB1] 
Blackreach Railroad 
Dwarven Luggage 
Dreamweaver (Ports of call)
Eagleview [Xbox] 
Wolfskull Manor A Riften home 
Asherz - Akemi The Snowelf Follower 
Lavender Menace Necklace 
Craft Everything 
Dol Khazun | by ak0d 
Realistic Food quantity and prices 
Tamriel Station Fleetford | by Tetradite 
Realistic Water Two (XB1) 
Stones of Barenziah Quest Markers
```

Comment: Is that listed according to load order? The mods I am familiar with seem to be in the right relative position, but is the list ordered using LOOT, Wrye Bash or something similar? (Also note that you are able to edit your question, so you can update your question with relevant information like that).

Comment: Yes this is my exact load order

Comment: I'm playing on Xbox1 so I don't have anything other than Skyrim creating my load order, although I have rearranged somethings myself.

Answer (score 1):

In [this Steam thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/489830/discussions/0/144512942755537852/?ctp=2) covering the same problem, the problem was found to lie with a mod called "*Breggan's Retreat*", and, sure enough, it seems part of the Dreamweaver mod. Disabling it should solve your problem. Be sure to have as little playing time as possible with the mod disabled to limit interactions with objects or scripts related to it:

- Load the save where you are at the Dwarven mechanism in Alftand where you have to transcribe the Elder Scroll, or save the game there.
- Exit the game (to desktop or main menu), **deactivate the *Dreamweaver* mod**, and reload that saved game.
- After leaving Alftand, be sure to immediately re-enable *Dreamweaver*.

Comment: I deactivated Dreamweaver and it still doesn't work...I'm on an Xbox1 btw